# Find the missing date between the two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the attendance for the staff, my stored procedure is working and returning the data. But i cannot see the off day. If no punch in or out it is not showing that day for the staff. How to return day even not punch in or out with the below stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME,
        @enddate DATETIME;

SET @startdate = '2018-07-21';
SET @enddate = '2018-08-21';

WITH calendardates AS 
(
     SELECT date = @startdate

     UNION ALL

     SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, date)
     FROM calendardates
     WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, date) = @enddate
)
SELECT       
    I.USERID,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, I.WORKDATE) WORKDATE,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CAST(I.CHECKTIME AS TIME), 100) AS INTIME, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CAST(O.CHECKTIME AS TIME), 100) AS OUTTIME,  
    DATEDIFF(n, I.CHECKTIME, O.CHECKTIME) / 60.00 AS WORKHRS,
    DATENAME(dw, (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.WORKDATE, 101))) AS DutyDay
FROM        
    vwInTime I 
LEFT JOIN 
    vwOutTime O ON I.UserID = O.UserID AND O.WorkDate = I.WorkDate
RIGHT JOIN 
    calendardates c ON I.WorkDate = c.date
WHERE     
    (I.WORKDATE BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) 
ORDER BY 
    UserID, WORKDATE
```

Sample data you cannot find here Friday for example.

```html
84 2018-07-21 00:00:00.000 9:06AM 6:19PM 9.216666 Saturday
84 2018-07-22 00:00:00.000 9:13AM 6:22PM 9.150000 Sunday
84 2018-07-23 00:00:00.000 9:02AM 6:29PM 9.450000 Monday
84 2018-07-24 00:00:00.000 9:06AM 6:29PM 9.383333 Tuesday
84 2018-07-25 00:00:00.000 9:02AM 6:55PM 9.883333 Wednesday
84 2018-07-26 00:00:00.000 9:08AM 6:36PM 9.466666 Thursday
84 2018-07-28 00:00:00.000 1:06PM NULL NULL Saturday
84 2018-07-29 00:00:00.000 1:01PM 10:00PM 8.983333 Sunday
84 2018-07-30 00:00:00.000 1:08PM 10:06PM 8.966666 Monday
84 2018-07-31 00:00:00.000 1:08PM 10:04PM 8.933333 Tuesday
84 2018-08-01 00:00:00.000 1:10PM 10:05PM 8.916666 Wednesday
84 2018-08-02 00:00:00.000 1:12PM 10:07PM 8.916666 Thursday
84 2018-08-04 00:00:00.000 9:07AM 6:25PM 9.300000 Saturday
```

Thank you.

Other try

```html
DECLARE @calendar AS TABLE (
      FullDate DATETIME NOT NULL)
declare  @startdate datetime='2018-07-21',
      @enddate datetime='2018-08-21'
   WHILE @startdate <= @enddate
BEGIN
INSERT  INTO @calendar
        (FullDate)
 Values(@startdate)
SET @startdate=DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startdate)
END

SELECT       I.USERID,
    Convert(datetime,I.WORKDATE) WORKDATE,
    c.FullDate,
    I.CHECKTIME INTIME, 
    O.CHECKTIME OUTTIME,
    Datediff(n,I.CHECKTIME,O.CHECKTIME) / 60.00 AS WORKHRS,
    datename(dw,(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.WORKDATE, 101))) As DutyDay
FROM        
             vwInTime I 
    LEFT JOIN vwOutTime O ON I.UserID = O.UserID AND 
             O.WorkDate = I.WorkDate
   Right Outer Join @calendar c On I.WorkDate=c.FullDate
             
WHERE     (I.WORKDATE BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) Order By WORKDATE
```

vwInTime

```html
SELECT     USERID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECKTIME, 112) AS WORKDATE, MIN(CHECKTIME) AS CHECKTIME, CHECKTYPE
FROM         dbo.CHECKINOUT
WHERE     (CHECKTYPE = 'I')
GROUP BY USERID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECKTIME, 112), CHECKTYPE
```

nwOutTime

```html
SELECT     USERID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECKTIME, 112) AS WORKDATE, MAX(CHECKTIME) AS CHECKTIME, CHECKTYPE
FROM         dbo.CHECKINOUT
WHERE     (CHECKTYPE = 'O')
GROUP BY USERID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CHECKTIME, 112), CHECKTYPE
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: i just put the sample data what i am getting now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try this.  RIGHT JOINS just make my head hurt.  For this pattern, start with your calendar table, one row per day.  Then LEFT JOIN your tables on the date column.

I think your error above is referencing an outer table in the WHERE clause, making the outer join an inner join.

Also you don't need a recursive CTE if you have a calandar table.  EG

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME
,@enddate DATETIME;

SET @startdate = '2018-07-21';
SET @enddate = '2018-08-21';
WITH calendardates
AS ( 
SELECT  date
FROM Calendar
WHERE date between @startdate and  @enddate
)
SELECT       I.USERID,
             Convert(datetime,I.WORKDATE) WORKDATE,
             CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(I.CHECKTIME AS TIME),100) As INTIME, 
             CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(O.CHECKTIME AS TIME),100) As OUTTIME,  
             Datediff(n,I.CHECKTIME,O.CHECKTIME) / 60.00 AS WORKHRS,
             datename(dw,(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.WORKDATE, 101))) As DutyDay
FROM calendardates c
LEFT JOIN vwInTime I 
  ON I.WorkDate = c.date
LEFT JOIN vwOutTime O
  ON I.UserID = O.UserID 
 AND O.WorkDate = I.WorkDate

ORDER BY UserID,WORKDATE
```

Comment: Why wouldn't right join do? Calendar dates is not generating the dates. If generated it would work, no?

Comment: Right joins should work.  I just never use them.  To easy to make mistakes like filtering on an outer table.

Comment: "Should work" ? You mean it may not? It would be a scary comment from Microsoft.

Comment: “Should work” meaning if you get the order of operations correct and don't make any other mistakes.  Note the problem appears to be in the WHERE clause where all the rows without a punch-in are filtered out.

Comment: Nope the problem was not there (it is part of the problem) but main problem was he was not generating calendar dates at all.

Comment: Yep. I didn’t even look at that part as generating ranges with a recursive CTE is a MAXRECURSION bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the purpose of that with block creating calendar dates was to generate dates from @startdate to @enddate (inclusive). If so your routine wouldn't do that, would it?

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME,
        @enddate DATETIME;

SET @startdate = '20180721';
SET @enddate = '20180821';

WITH calendardates
AS (
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(d, @startdate, @enddate) + 1)
           DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.object_id) - 1, @startdate) AS [date]
    FROM sys.all_columns t1
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns t2
      ON t2.object_id = t1.object_id
)
SELECT       I.USERID,
             coalesce(Convert(datetime,I.WORKDATE), c.Date) as WORKDATE,
             CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(I.CHECKTIME AS TIME),100) As INTIME, 
             CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(O.CHECKTIME AS TIME),100) As OUTTIME,  
             Datediff(n,I.CHECKTIME,O.CHECKTIME) / 60.00 AS WORKHRS,
             datename(dw,coalesce(Convert(datetime,I.WORKDATE,101), c.Date)) As DutyDay
FROM        calendardates c 
LEFT JOIN  vwInTime I ON I.WorkDate = c.date 
LEFT JOIN vwOutTime O ON I.UserID = O.UserID AND 
                                                 O.WorkDate = I.WorkDate
Order By UserID,coalesce(Convert(datetime,I.WORKDATE), c.Date);
```

Note: What would you do with NULL userIDs?

EDIT: Here is the version that deals with NULL UserIDs too:

```
declare @workTable TABLE
    ([USERID] int, [WORKDATE] datetime, [INTIME] varchar(10), [OUTTIME] varchar(10), [WORKHRS] varchar(8), [DutyDay] varchar(9));

INSERT INTO @workTable
    ([USERID], [WORKDATE], [INTIME], [OUTTIME], [WORKHRS], [DutyDay])
VALUES
    (84, '2018-07-21', '9:06AM', '6:19PM', '9.216666', 'Saturday'),
    (84, '2018-07-22', '9:13AM', '6:22PM', '9.150000', 'Sunday'),
    (84, '2018-07-23', '9:02AM', '6:29PM', '9.450000', 'Monday'),
    (84, '2018-07-24', '9:06AM', '6:29PM', '9.383333', 'Tuesday'),
    (84, '2018-07-25', '9:02AM', '6:55PM', '9.883333', 'Wednesday'),
    (84, '2018-07-26', '9:08AM', '6:36PM', '9.466666', 'Thursday'),
    (84, '2018-07-28', '1:06PM', NULL, NULL, 'Saturday'),
    (84, '2018-07-29', '1:01PM', '10:00PM', '8.983333', 'Sunday'),
    (84, '2018-07-30', '1:08PM', '10:06PM', '8.966666', 'Monday'),
    (84, '2018-07-31', '1:08PM', '10:04PM', '8.933333', 'Tuesday'),
    (84, '2018-08-01', '1:10PM', '10:05PM', '8.916666', 'Wednesday'),
    (84, '2018-08-02', '1:12PM', '10:07PM', '8.916666', 'Thursday'),
    (84, '2018-08-04', '9:07AM', '6:25PM', '9.300000', 'Saturday');

DECLARE @startdate DATETIME,
        @enddate DATETIME;

SET @startdate = '20180721';
SET @enddate = '20180821';

WITH calendardates
AS (
SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(d, @startdate, @enddate) + 1)
            DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.object_id) - 1, @startdate) AS [date]
    FROM sys.all_columns t1
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns t2
        ON t2.object_id = t1.object_id
),
userDates AS 
(
  SELECT [date], USERID
  FROM calendardates
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM @workTable) t 
)
    SELECT       c.USERID,
                 c.Date as WORKDATE,
                 INTIME, 
                 OUTTIME,  
                 WORKHRS,
                 datename(dw,c.Date) As DutyDay
    FROM        
                userdates c 
                LEFT JOIN @WorkTable wt
    ON wt.WorkDate = c.date AND wt.USERID = c.USERID
    Order By UserID,c.Date;
```

And here is the [DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e6085112871494e1b9075db88bd53b47)

Comment: it returns me the same result as what I am getting. if not punch in or out from the staff, for example, emp101- he didn't punch on 2018-08-01, when I am generating above query it will not show 2018-08-01. skip to next day only. how i can see even that day bcoz that's the off day for him.

Comment: You have two problems (was three) in that SQL basically. 1) You are implying a filter so putting missing dates out of result 2) You are not bringing in any date from CalendarDates. I will edit it for you and also convert to a left join which is easier to manage (but ignore that right joins wouldn't work, they work).

Comment: @NAJEEB, you should think what you would do with null IDs. (Maybe do a cartesian join first? - if data is not a lot)

Comment: sorry for the late, i dont have any null userid.

Comment: please check my second try also. from that script nothing is returning. manually i added the weekdays to table.

Comment: @NAJEEB, you are not really following the code I gave. Check edited second SQL and the DBFiddle demo.

Comment: thanks cetin but please not the joins are view "LEFT JOIN  vwInTime I ON I.WorkDate = c.date 
LEFT JOIN vwOutTime O ON I.UserID = O.UserID" am adding my view in the question area

Answer (score 0):

Issue is coming because where clause does not contain condition for calendardates. Add the condition and it should work

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME,
        @enddate DATETIME;

SET @startdate = '2018-07-21';
SET @enddate = '2018-08-21';

WITH calendardates AS 
(
     SELECT date = @startdate

     UNION ALL

     SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, date)
     FROM calendardates
     WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, date) = @enddate
)
SELECT       
    I.USERID,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, I.WORKDATE) WORKDATE,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CAST(I.CHECKTIME AS TIME), 100) AS INTIME, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CAST(O.CHECKTIME AS TIME), 100) AS OUTTIME,  
    DATEDIFF(n, I.CHECKTIME, O.CHECKTIME) / 60.00 AS WORKHRS,
    DATENAME(dw, (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.WORKDATE, 101))) AS DutyDay
FROM        
    vwInTime I 
LEFT JOIN 
    vwOutTime O ON I.UserID = O.UserID AND O.WorkDate = I.WorkDate
RIGHT JOIN 
    calendardates c ON I.WorkDate = c.date
WHERE     
    (I.WORKDATE BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) OR c.date is NULL
ORDER BY 
    UserID, WORKDATE
```

Another way you can try is to shift the condition with vwIntime

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME,
        @enddate DATETIME;

SET @startdate = '2018-07-21';
SET @enddate = '2018-08-21';

WITH calendardates AS 
(
     SELECT date = @startdate

     UNION ALL

     SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, date)
     FROM calendardates
     WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, date) = @enddate
)
SELECT       
    I.USERID,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, I.WORKDATE) WORKDATE,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CAST(I.CHECKTIME AS TIME), 100) AS INTIME, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CAST(O.CHECKTIME AS TIME), 100) AS OUTTIME,  
    DATEDIFF(n, I.CHECKTIME, O.CHECKTIME) / 60.00 AS WORKHRS,
    DATENAME(dw, (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.WORKDATE, 101))) AS DutyDay
FROM        
    (SELECT * FROM vwInTime
     WHERE (WORKDATE BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
    ) I 
LEFT JOIN 
    vwOutTime O ON I.UserID = O.UserID AND O.WorkDate = I.WorkDate
RIGHT JOIN 
    calendardates c ON I.WorkDate = c.date
ORDER BY 
    UserID, WORKDATE
```

Comment: this one return me only one day thats the first day "2018-07-21" with all the userid.